# Asp.Net not using the handler resolved in PageHandlerFactory

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ihttphandler

I am trying to intercept the calling of the pages in Asp.Net, so I can change the object before it is used.
I am providing a simplified code, to illustrate the problem.
By debugging, I step into the CustomPageHandlerFactory, and I see it using the base method to get an instance of the page. But this instance does not seem to be passed forward.
The hashcode of the gethandler's object and the instance's hashcode of the page differ.

Shouldn't they be same?

the page:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public bool Throw { get; set; }

    public _Default()
    {
        Throw = true;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThrowException();
    }

    public virtual void ThrowException() 
    {
        if (Throw)
        {
            throw new Exception("Non sense error!");
        }            
    }
}
```

the handlerfactory:

```
public class CustomPageHandlerFactory : PageHandlerFactory
{
    public override IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string virtualPath, string path)
    {
        var page = base.GetHandler(context, requestType, virtualPath, path);

        ((_Default)page).Throw = false;

        return page;
    }
}
```

and a chunk of the config:

```
(...)
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="CustomPageHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="Example.CustomPageHandlerFactory" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>      
        <remove verb="*" path="*.aspx" />
        <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Example.CustomPageHandlerFactory" />
    </httpHandlers>
    (...)
```

As pointed out by @Ondrej Svejdar, I should add the framework versions:

- c# 4.5
- asp.Net 4.0
- IIS 7.5
- Visual studio 2013

Comment: Tried the code and it is behaving as excepted (it doesn't throw an exception). What framework/web server version are you using ?

Comment: Thank you, I added the info to the question.

Comment: I used this same code to test this behavior

Comment: I went even further: I removed the handles for aspx, using the remove tag for `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit`, `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit`, `PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0`, `SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0`, `PageHandlerFactory-Integrated`, `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0` and `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64`. Forcing it to use my custom factory.

Comment: I got the same results

Comment: Then, when I commented my handle line, It does not route to default.aspx, but if I write the full url, it works.

Comment: I literally wrote on the GetHandle: `return null;`. Still calls the page.

Comment: On visual studio 2010, it works...

Comment: Tried .NET4.0/.NET4.5/IIS7.5 - and it works (Visual Studio version is irrelevant when running the code from IIS).  Have you tried it with your example or were you trying the "full version" :) ? There can be other things that can "hijack" your page (like http module, rerouting to other handler in some part of flow, etc.).

Comment: Funny thing... when I created a new empty web project, it worked. When I used the default webform template, from visual studio, It did not

Comment: When inspecting the objects I got this, from the template project: the handler factory Assembly: `Example, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`, and from the page: Assembly: `App_Web_h0rtuo2m, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Comment: Is there an way to ensure they are being called at the same assembly? And why were they different?

Comment: First assembly is compiled in visual studio, second seems like it is compiled by IIS on the fly (i.e. it seems like web site project where source for page factory is in the app_code directory). Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx If you're using web site project, I'd recommend moving that factory to separate assembly (i.e. Example.Factory.dll) and just referencing the Example.Factory from the web site project.

Comment: It is a good idea... Thanks for the help. I just wish i could force the application to use the same dll....